# 80s or older movie where spike-like tentacles come out of the mans face?

Tags: story-identification

My daughter asked me what was the first horror movie I remember. I can only recall one scene.

This is an old movie probably 80's or before that, also I was quite wussy at the time so it might not be a horror movie.

The scene is where the guy (baddy) facing the main character with his back and is writing something on the whiteboard, and as a character is observing him from behind. He starts from writing letters writing faster and faster and then it's gibberish more and more like just dashes and dots and then he (baddy) that was writing turns around and spikelike tentacles come out of his face.
Then the character starts running after that I think.

Also, I think there were at the end of movie characters with white suits turning some sort of wheel to let some creature out.

Comment: Worth checking the [TV Tropes page for Flower Mouth](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FlowerMouth) and some of the related pages from [Monster Mouth](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MonsterMouth).

Comment: This sounds like the 1988 TV movie "Something is Out There", about an alien monster, escaped from a prison ship, coming to earth. The arachnid; like monster inhabits human bodies, and energies to fight when threatened. I recall a scene like the one that you describe-but with a chalkboard.

Comment: @StanleyWebb Hey Stanley, indeed this is the movie, thank you so much.
Could you post your comment as an answer please, I would like to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like the 1988 TV movie "Something is Out There", about an alien monster, escaped from a prison ship, coming to earth. The arachnid-like monster inhabits human bodies, and emerges to fight when threatened. I recall a scene like the one that you describe-but with a chalkboard.

[image]